# "I don't agree totally" vs. "I don't totally agree" vs. "I totally don't agree"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, word-order, negation

What is the difference between the following?

> 1. I don't agree with him totally.
> 2. I don't totally agree with him.
> 3. I totally don't agree with him.

I'm puzzled at the meaning of negative sentences which contain the word "totally" or other similar word. 
And I want to ask one more question. In addition to the expression of "not at all", is there any other way to express this meaning?

Comment: As an aside, it is "difference between". Always. There is no such thing as "difference among". That immediately marks you as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Adverbs can niche in a number of different places.

Comment: Isn't "between" used only if there are two aspects mentioned?

Comment: ... Certainly not. That's the 'simple rule' teachers trot out (and sadly perhaps believe to exist). Have a look here on ELU to see the actual usages of 'between' and 'among/st'.

Comment: Please note: I totally don't agree with him. = modern,slangy usage. Kids say "totally" without placing it in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't agree with him totally," and "I don't totally agree with him," mean the same thing: *"my agreement with him is not total."* The speaker agrees, but has doubts.

In this case, "I agree with him totally" is the sentiment negated by "don't".

"I totally don't agree with him" means *"my disagreement with him is total."* It is a declaration of complete disagreement. You might also say, "I don't agree with him at all."

In this case, "I don't agree with him" is the sentiment emphasised by "totally".

Comment: @Mike: This is very much an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) level question, so hopefully there shouldn't be any/many learners reading the above two comments. But it seems to me that repeating the erroneous use of ***does*** instead of ***is*** would probably leave OP *less* competent in English than before he asked the question! :)

Comment: @Allen: The third sentence is grammatically correct, but might be a little informal. It might be better to say, "I don't agree with him at all," or "I completely disagree with him."

Answer (score -1):

Agree can be either used as an intransitive or transitive verb, so adverb comes after the verb.
*I fought bravely*
*I ran quickly*

For transitive verb, it comes after the indirect object.
*I do not agree with him totally.*